# Orbeon multilingual strange behaviour in radiobuttons

Tags: orbeon

I am adding some multilingual support to my orbeon forms. For this scope, I have added several resoruces with different languages `<resource xml:lang="en">[...]</resource><resource xml:lang="it">[...]</resource>`

I have discover that, if I have two languages, the radio buttons options, appears repeated (I can see two times each answer). A simple example is:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
    <xh:head>
            <xh:meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <xh:title>RadioButton</xh:title>
            <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
                    <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                            <metadata>
                                    <application-name>TestForm</application-name>
                                    <form-name>RadioButton_v1</form-name>
                                    <title xml:lang="en">RadioButton</title>
                                    <description xml:lang="en">Version: 1. Modification date: 2015-10-15 11:17:32. Publication date: 2015-10-15 11:17:32.</description>
                            <singleton>false</singleton>
            </metadata>
                    </xf:instance>
                    <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
                            <form>
                                    <Category>
                                            <Question>Answer</Question>
                                    </Category>
                            </form>
                    </xf:instance>
                    <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                            <xf:bind id="Category-bind" name="Category" ref="/form/Category">
                                    <xf:bind id="Question-bind" name="Question" readonly="false()" ref="Question"
                         required="true()"/>
                            </xf:bind> 
        </xf:bind>
                    <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
                            <attachments>
                                    <css filename="" mediatype="text/css" size=""/>
                                    <pdf filename="" mediatype="application/pdf" size=""/>
                            </attachments>
                    </xf:instance>
                    <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:readonly="false">
                            <resources>
                                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                                            <Category>
                                                    <label>Category</label>
                                                    <hint/>
                                                    <alert/>                                              
                                                    <Question>
                                                            <label>Question</label>
                                                            <hint/>
                                                            <alert/>
                                                            <item>
                                                                    <label>Answer</label>
                                                                    <hint/>
                                                                    <value>Answer</value>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item>
                                                                    <label>Answer2</label>
                                                                    <hint/>
                                                                    <value>Answer2</value>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item>
                                                                    <label>Answer3</label>
                                                                    <hint/>
                                                                    <value>Answer3</value>
                                                            </item>
                                                    </Question>
                                            </Category>
                                    </resource>       
                                    <resource xml:lang="nl">
                                            <Category>
                                                    <label>Category</label>
                                                    <hint/>
                                                    <alert/>
                                                    <Question>
                                                            <label>Question</label>
                                                            <hint/>
                                                            <alert/>
                                                            <item>
                                                                    <label>Answer</label>
                                                                    <hint/>
                                                                    <value>Answer</value>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item>
                                                                    <label>Answer2</label>
                                                                    <hint/>
                                                                    <value>Answer2</value>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item>
                                                                    <label>Answer3</label>
                                                                    <hint/>
                                                                    <value>Answer3</value>
                                                            </item>
                                                    </Question>
                                            </Category>
                                    </resource>
                            </resources>
                    </xf:instance>
                    <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                            <request/>
                    </xf:instance>
                    <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                            <response/>
                    </xf:instance>                       
            </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
            <fr:view>
                    <fr:body xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                 xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                                    <fr:section bind="Category-bind" id="Category-control">
                                            <xf:label mediatype="text/html"
                          ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/Category/label"/>
                                            <xf:hint ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/Category/hint"/>
                                            <xf:alert ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/Category/alert"/>
                                            <xh:tr>
                                                    <xh:td>
                                                            <xf:select1 appearance="full" bind="Question-bind" id="Question-control">
                                                                    <xf:label mediatype="text/html"
                                      ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/Category/Question/label"/>
                                                                    <xf:hint ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/Category/Question/hint"/>
                                                                    <xf:alert ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/Category/Question/alert"/>
                                                                    <xf:itemset class="webforms-element webforms-answer"
                                        ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/Category/Question/item">
                                                                            <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                                                            <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                                                            <xf:hint ref="hint"/>
                                                                    </xf:itemset>
                                                            </xf:select1>
                                                    </xh:td>
                                            </xh:tr>
                                    </fr:section>
                    </fr:body>
            </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Where the result is:

[image: Radio Button with repeated answers due to multilingual support]

An small research and test, seems that the issue is related to the "nested" questions inside the section definition.

```
<Category>
            <label>Category</label>
            <hint/>
            <alert/>
            <Question>
                    <label>Question</label>
                    <hint/>
                    <alert/>
            <item>
                    <label>Answer</label>
                    <hint/>
                    <value>Answer</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                    <label>Answer2</label>
                    <hint/>
                    <value>Answer2</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                     <label>Answer3</label>
                    <hint/>
                    <value>Answer3</value>
            </item>
     </Question>
</Category>
```

That if I change it to:

```
<Category>
            <label>Category</label>
            <hint/>
            <alert/>
</Category>
<Question>
            <label>Question</label>
            <hint/>
               <alert/>
            <item>
                    <label>Answer</label>
                    <hint/>
                    <value>Answer</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                    <label>Answer2</label>
                    <hint/>
                    <value>Answer2</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                     <label>Answer3</label>
                    <hint/>
                    <value>Answer3</value>
            </item>
</Question>
```

Seems that works fine. I know the Orbeon builder does not do nested elements in the resources part, but in general I would prefer to do on this way and I think that is more clear for reading (or to use the XPath of the element).

There is any way to solve this behaviour using nested elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question in your last paragraph: Form Runner doesn't expect resources to be nested that way.

In essence, Form Runner expects whatever Form Builder produces. If you're not using Form Builder to edit the source of the form, or do changes to the source that Form Builder created, it is up to you to make sure that those changes are inline with what Form Builder would normally generate, and is understood by Form Runner.

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand why in almost all the definitions of the form (model, binding, body, ...), all use nested elements, but in the resources not. Only for this, you cannot repeat elements in nested elements because you cannot find a xpath expression to the correct resource.

Comment: I think the simple answer is that resources did not need to be nested (unlike controls, binds and the XML data), so they were not.